# откуда в массиве char берётся мусор, превышающий размер массива?

Tags: c++, файлы, char

мне нужно было прочитать 2D массив char из файла. всё работает, но при выводе массива появляется очень много мусора. я в курсе про ноль в конце строки, но если его нет, то будет прочитан весь массив. я выделяю по 5*5 байт. откуда здесь берётся столько мусора?

файл:

```
5 5
*****
** **
*****
*****
*****
```

вывод:

```
5 5

*****¤¤¤¤║|g
** **¤¤¤¤
*****¤¤¤¤▌
*****¤¤¤¤
*****¤¤¤¤
```

код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
char** Map;
string str;
int x = 0, y = 0;
int main() {
    ifstream f;
    f.open("maps\\map.txt");
    f >> x;
    f >> y;

    getline(f, str); // перевод на следующую строку

    cout << x << " " << y << "\n";
    
    Map = new char* [y];
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        Map[i] = new char[x];
        getline(f, str);
        str.copy(Map[i], x);
    }
    f.close();

    cout << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
        cout << Map[i] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: «я в курсе про ноль в конце строки» — ну если в курсе, то чего ж не поставили-то его? Оттого и мусор, что вы вылезаете за пределы выделенной памяти для строки

Comment: потому что char здесь выступает в качестве массива маленьких int + массив char[y][x] представлен в памяти как y массивов по x символов подряд. мусор должен быть только в последней строке или должно выводится часть следующих

Comment: Мне кажется вы должны прямо выделить место под последний символ с кодом 0 и записать этот 0 в конец каждой строки.

Comment: «массив char[y][x] представлен в памяти как y массивов по x символов подряд» — вообще нет, вы же выделяете шесть отдельных маленьких кусов памяти, а не один большой. Никто не обещал, что шесть отдельных аллокаций расположатся строго последовательно

Comment: «char здесь выступает в качестве массива маленьких int» — ну так и не пытайтесь тогда работать с ними как со строкой.

Comment: Тогда выводите не как `cout << Map[i]`, а как `for(int j = 0; j<x; ++j) cout << Map[i][j];`

Comment: "...если его нет, то будет прочитан весь массив". Если бы только весь массив! Будет прочитана вся, абсолютно вся, оперативная память. До первого встреченного нуля или до срабатывания защиты памяти.

Comment: спасибо за объяснение